# How to exclude particular axis from accelerometer code?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, accelerometer

I am using the accelerometer function in my project and I need to exclude certain axises from the code. I want to exclude Y & Z and only use X. Thanks

Here is the code I'm using.

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

    double const kThreshold = 1.5;
    //    double const kThreshold = 2.0;
    if ( fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kThreshold)
```

Comment: From what you wrote it's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check for acceleration above kThreshold for the x-axis, then change:

```
if ( fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kThreshold
        || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kThreshold)
```

to:

```
if ( fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold)
```